# Error con el identificador en Oracle

Tags: oracle, apex

Quisiera saber que tengo mal en este código, me sale el siguiente error:

> ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 8: PLS-00201: el identificador 'WKSP_UEB.PGK_BIENESTAR.FN_OBXES' se debe declarar

CÓDIGO:

```
"#OWNER#"."PGK_BIENESTAR.FN_OBXES"(
"ESTUDIANTE_DADO" => :P14_ESTUDIANTE_DADO);
```

Comment: Sencillo: existe el objeto `WKSP_UEB.PGK_BIENESTAR.FN_OBXES`? Supone uno que es una función con un parámetro de entrada y tu ejecución la está buscando en el esquema WKSP_UEB, paquete PGK_BIENESTAR

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a validar que el paquete exista, es importante revisar que tanto la especificación y el cuerpo del paquete se encuentren válidos.